# Is there a way to get the Broadcast address of a network in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows, ip, uwp, broadcast

I am currently porting a .Net project to UWP and I have no access to most of the System.Net namespaces, ergo I cant use the IPAddress class to get the Broadcast property I need

```
socket?.Send(discoveringMessage, discoveringMessage.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, port));
```

Is there any replacements or workarounds for this issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Wouldn't you use the Loopback iP address 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Instead of the broadcast? What do you mean?

Comment: I just checked the Net Library and IPAddress.Broadcast is a constant 255.255.255.255.

Comment: Oh so I can totally hardcode it then?

Comment: Yes. Yes, Yes ,

Comment: It worked, add it as an aswer so I may upvote you buddy